# PocketSphinx own keyword spotting in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, keyword-spotting

I want to implement a keyword spotting based on PocketSphinx for an Android app.

PocketSphinx is new for me. I started with the PocketsphinxAndroidDemo from their repo.
Then I have imported the project in Eclipse and have build and deployed the demo app on my phone. The demo recognized the commands deposit and withdraw and numbers fine. I have not installed any other lib or tool.

Now I want to recognize my own keywords and follew the CMUSphinx tutorial. Therefore I created an own DIC and LM file using "Sphinx knowledge base generator" and have included in the assets subfolder of the project. The corpus I use:

```
open browser
new e-mail
forward
backward
next window
last window
open music player
```

I have modified SpeechRecognizer the following:

```
config.setString("-jsgf", joinPath(dataDir, "dialog.gram")); // unmodified
config.setString("-dict", joinPath(dataDir, "lm/2914.dic"));
config.setString("-lm", joinPath(dataDir, "lm/2914.lm"));
config.setString("-hmm", joinPath(dataDir, "hmm/hub4wsj_sc_8k")); // unmodified
```

Then I have started the app again and got the following errors:

```
11-21 12:48:18.758: E/cmusphinx(15521): "fsg_search.c", line 334: The word 'withdraw' is missing in the dictionary
```

and

```
11-21 12:48:26.375: A/libc(15521): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000001c (code=1), thread 15557 (SpeechRecognize)
```

I know "withdraw" is a word of the former dictionary.

What do I have to modify in the grammar file?

I also read this tutorial http://www.aiaioo.com/cms/index.php?id=28 and used the acoustic model and the phonetic dictionary from there. I have modified the SpeechRecognizer again. While the app is starting, I see the ressources were loaded correctly. But then I got the same error.

Can someone please tell me please what the problem is?
What steps do I have to do to get my spotting running?

Comment: There can be issues with `syncAsset`, e.g. if a file already exists it won't overwrite it even if files aren't the same. We hope to fix all of them soon. Meanwhile I recommend you to copy resources manually or write your own implementation.

Comment: Which resources do you mean and to which target?
And what should I implement by myself?

Comment: I mean all files located under `assets/`. Currently they are unpacked on the target device using `syncAsset()`. I recommend you for now to copy them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change entries in a dictionary file to ALL CAPS. Try using this for your dictionary file:

```
OPEN BROWSER
NEW E-MAIL
FORWARD
BACKWARD
NEXT WINDOW
LAST WINDOW
OPEN MUSIC PLAYER
```

This worked for me.